# Jolt - copy values from one array to another and change keys

Tags: json, jolt

I have a problem with the Jolt library. I tried different approaches but I was not able to get the output that I want. The main thing is that I want to get values from one array and copy them, but also change some of the key names.

```
"amout" -> "value"
"desc" -> "description"
"issued" -> "issueDate"
```

**Input:**

```
{
  "payments": [
    {
      "value": "128.90",
      "title": "Opłata za kurs poprawkowy",
      "desc": "Opłata za kurs poprawkowy z przedmiotu Architektura Komputerów. Prowadzący Janusz Kowalski.",
      "instalment": "1",
      "paymentDate": "2020-01-20",
      "issued": "2020-01-20",
      "status": "1"
    },
    {
      "value": "128.90",
      "title": "Opłata za kurs poprawkowy",
      "desc": "Opłata za kurs poprawkowy z przedmiotu Architektura Komputerów. Prowadzący Janusz Kowalski.",
      "instalment": "2",
      "paymentDate": "2020-02-20",
      "issued": "2020-02-20",
      "status": "2"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Output**

```
{
  "payments": [
    {
      "amount": "128.90",
      "title": "Opłata za kurs poprawkowy",
      "description": "Opłata za kurs poprawkowy z przedmiotu Architektura Komputerów. Prowadzący Janusz Kowalski.",
      "instalment": "1",
      "paymentDate": "2020-01-20",
      "issueDate": "2020-01-20",
      "status": "1"
    },
    {
      "amount": "128.90",
      "title": "Opłata za kurs poprawkowy",
      "description": "Opłata za kurs poprawkowy z przedmiotu Architektura Komputerów. Prowadzący Janusz Kowalski.",
      "instalment": "2",
      "paymentDate": "2020-02-20",
      "issueDate": "2020-02-20",
      "status": "2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a classic shift operation. You will need to iterate over the itens of payments array (using *) and "move" each atribute back to its object at the same index (&1) of the payments array:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "payments": {
        "*": {
          "value": "payments.[&1].amount",
          "desc": "payments.[&1].description",
          "issued": "payments.[&1].issueDate",
          "*": "payments.[&1].&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you! I created a similar spec, but without **&1** and I couldn't make it work. I've just found the Jolt slide deck that explains all, but I think that it requires better documentation than a presentation :(

Comment: I find this documentation https://intercom.help/godigibee/en/articles/4044359-transformer-getting-to-know-jolt from an integration tool that uses jolt one of the best available out there so far, maybe you want to check this out.

Answer (score 1):

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "payments": {
        // for each item in array
        "*": {
          // change keys
          "value": "payments[&1].amount",
          "desc": "payments[&1].description",
          "issued": "payments[&1].issueDate",
          // copy everything else
          "*": {
            "@": "payments[&2].&"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```